# Call to undefined function imagefttext()

Tags: php, gd, freetype

I have this script:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 150);
imagettftext($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);
imagepng($im);
?>
```

I compiled with:

```
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-sockets' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl' '--with-gd' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-jpeg-dir=/opt' '--with-png-dir=/opt' '--with-gettext' '--with-imap' '--with-imap-ssl' '--with-kerberos' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-mysql' '--with-mysqli' '--with-openssl' '--with-zlib' '--enable-zip'
```

I am getting the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imagefttext() in /root/test.php on line 9
```

I am running CentOS, and I have gd-devel, freetype-devel, among other packages. I'm not sure why it's not working. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you are showing is differing from the error message

Comment: My bad. Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagettftext()

Comment: `This function requires both the GD library and the » FreeType library.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be at least two `.configure` flags missing:

```
 --with-freetype-dir=/usr --enable-gd-native-ttf
```

see the [GD installation instructions.](http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php)

Answer (score 2):

If the error message is to be believed, you probably meant to type [imagettftext()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) rather than imagefttext() in your code.